# Making a program that prints from x to y numbers depending on what the user asks

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm new to Java sorry, I have to make this program in which it will ask the user two numbers, from those two numbers take the intervals that can be divided by 3 and then make an average of them.

I'm only focusing on making it print all the numbers since I'm trying to go step by step.

I have tried two things

On this first code it asks for both numbers but doesn't print anything

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

double b = scanner.nextDouble();
  
for ( double a = scanner.nextDouble() ; a <= b; a++)
{
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

On this second code it asks for 3 inputs and it prints the loop normally if the last input is equal to the first, I think I can see why this is happening but I don't know how to fix it:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    double a = scanner.nextDouble();
    double b = scanner.nextDouble();
  
    for ( a = scanner.nextDouble() ; a <= b; a++)
    {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest using int's rather than double's.

Comment: I'm using doubles because some outputs may be fractions (because it has to be divided by 3 and then make an average from all of them)

Comment: You didn't say anything about fractions above. As for checking about division by three, that is easier with int's than it is with double's. ``int i = n; if (i % 3 == 0) {...}``

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't thought it would be relevant, I'll change it

Comment: In your second example, you ask for three numbers (call scanner.nextDouble() three times), but you only have two variables (a and b). You assign a twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the loop counter with the value of `a` and make the loop iterate until the value of `b` as shown below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        int b = scanner.nextInt();
        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
                sum += i;
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Average: " + sum / count);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
2
10
3
6
9
Average: 6.0
```

**-OR-**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        double a = scanner.nextDouble();
        double b = scanner.nextDouble();
        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        for (double i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
                sum += i;
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Average: " + sum / count);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
2
10
3.0
6.0
9.0
Average: 6.0
```